# Is a ASP.NET MVC 2 app forward compatible to ASP.NET MVC 3 framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been working on a ASP.NET MVC 2 project and i've been thinking if i should migrate it to ASP.NET MVC 3.

I'm not sure though if it's forward compatible and i dont have to re work that much on my existing application.

Another issue i have is if migrating would affect the behavior of my Dev Express controls. Or any third party control for that matter.

Comment: Is your MVC 2 app already on .net 4? if not, then that's a second conversion (.net 3.5 => .net 4) which is mostly smooth but may have caveats on it's own.

Comment: its already on .net 4 so i guess its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can migrate your MVC2 app to MVC3 safely.  http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/07/28/migrating-asp-net-mvc-2-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Comment: sorry, but this answer is incorrect. see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

yes asp.net mvc 2 is forward compatible. We have fairly large product and we faced no problems. you can check the following instructions to upgrade.

[how to upgrade your exisitng asp.net mvc 2 project to asp.net mvc 3](http://www.adeelhussain.com/how-to-upgrade-your-exisitng-asp-net-mvc-2-project-to-asp-net-mvc-3/)

Answer (score 0):

Moving from MVC 2 to MVC 3 was much easier than the move from version 1 to 2 for me.

The only issue I encountered was the Nullable action parameters always being null (even when there is a value)... but I think that was just a bug in RC2.

Answer (score 0):

The other responders are not correct. MVC 2 apps will continue to run in tha majority of cases on MVC 3. However, there's a a few breaking changes that could

- prevent your application from compiling
- cause the application to fail at runtime
- introduce functional changes to your site that could affect users

While this should be quite rare (and depends entirely on whether you use features whose behaviors have changed), please make sure to read the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes) and test your application to make sure it works.